# Handle multiple Notifications / Stacking Notifications from GCM

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I just implemented GCM and notifications in my Android app, coming from an Apache/PHP-based webserver.
The notifications are already working, but I'm stuck at stacking the notifications, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

### What I'm trying to do

I have two types of notifications in my app, using data coming from the GCM Service:
**Type 1 (Messages):**

```
[data] => Array
(
    [t] => 1
    [other data...]
)
```

**Type 2 (News):**

```
[data] => Array
(
    [t] => 2
    [other data...]
)
```

These 2 types are completely different notifications, and I would like to stack both of them separate from each other, but I can't get this to work.
I would like to stack them like this, as soon as there are multiple notifications:

**Default View**
[image: Stacking Notifications]

---

**Expanded View**
[image: Stacking Notifications 2]

---

### What I tried

**2 Notification IDs  and Atomic Integer**
I tried to use 2 different notification IDs, so that notifications with the same type get overidden.

```
if (msg.get("t").toString().equals("1")) {
    notificationNumber = messageCounter.incrementAndGet();
} else {
    notificationNumber = newsCounter.incrementAndGet();
}
[...]
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setNumber(notificationNumber);
```

If 2 messages are sent at the same time, everything works fine and the counter shows 2. But if there is a short delay between two notifications, the counter switches to 1.

**Unique Notification IDs**
I also tried to use unique IDs generated with

```
Date now = new Date();
Notification_id = now.getTime();
```

so that there isn't no stacking or overriding at all.

### Question

How can I solve my problem? Can I access the content of the previously sent notifications, so that I can show every message in one line, like in the expanded view of Gmail? How can I check which / how many notifications are currently displayed?
Long question, thank you very much!

Comment: You are mixing between notification number (which is displayed as part of the notification) and notification ID (which controls overriding of notifications) and it's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found the solution and ended up using atomic integers, but in a seperated class:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Global {
    public static AtomicInteger Counter1 = new AtomicInteger();
    public static AtomicInteger Counter2 = new AtomicInteger();
}
```

To reset the counter after the application  opening, i put this in my MainActivity (called in `onCreate()` and `onResume()`:

```
private void clearNotifications(){        
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancelAll();

    Global.Counter1.set(0);
    Global.Counter2.set(0);
}
```

When I create the notification, I check the counter:

```
Counter1 = Global.Counter1.incrementAndGet();
ContentText = (Counter1 < 2) ? /* Single notification */ : /* Stacking */;
```