# Android updating notifications

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm creating an application which is connected to GCM services in which the GCM client uses notification to inform the app user that there is an incoming message.

Based on what is provided in the official Android documentation,

http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html#Updating

How do apps like whatsapp, gmail and hangouts handle updating of the contents of a notification?

Scenario:

1. I have contact A who sends me 5 dollars. (Notification appears)

   ```
   [NotificationIcon] [Notification Title]               [Timestamp]
                      A sent $5                          [Total $5]
   ```
2. Contact B sends me 6 dollars (Same notification should update itself to say the following)

   ```
   [NotificationIcon] [Notification Title]               [Timestamp]
                      A sent $5
                      B sent $6                          [Total $11]
   ```

I do not have access to the previous notification so i'm unable to append the text from the new GCM message.

I'm sure this is a common problem but the solution doesn't seem to be available at the moment easily. Any help is appreciated.

The current code i've written is the GCM client sample code with basic modification to display my content.

EDIT:

The closest answer i could find was here [Handle multiple Notifications / Stacking Notifications from GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101949/handle-multiple-notifications-stacking-notifications-from-gcm?rq=1) but i'm looking for other known solutions.

Comment: after GCM message comes to your program save(db, shared preferences, flat file) the results and show notification ... then if another message comes, save and check older ones ... if time between them are smaller than some amount then update notification with both messages ..

Comment: @Selvin when you mean save the results, you mean persist it on local memory? And what is the event for me to notify that the notification has been cleared or clicked on, so that i can clear out the "saved" results